# requests_html: How to structure code to include sub-pages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests-html

How to structure my code to include pagination sometimes from within a running loop. I am not using `def`, yet. Maybe that's the answer. But after looking for several days I'm stuck. I'm looking for a high level answer.

Here is my basic structure:

```
import requests_html
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from requests_html import HTML
import re
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from random import randint
session = HTMLSession()

from url retrieve links for states with providers

(loop) from states retrieve urls for cities with providers

        from city_page in cities:
            Retrieve data about individual providers from each "card"
            (max 10 "cards" per page) Everything is fine up to this point.

            Here is where I am lost. Sometimes a city only has one or two providers and that works 
            just fine. Sometimes there are 50+ providers at 10 per page. There are links to the 
            extra pages at the bottom of the container/ [<element>].
```

How do I structure my code in general to loop through the extra pages when they are present? And then return to the containing loop so it can proceed to the next city? I have no idea how to inject the extra urls into the existing loop.

Comment: Suggest you start doing it and get something working, then - and only if needed - see if there are opportunities to improve the code.

Comment: Thanks barny. I have have tried, I'm working on it at the moment trying a new def function, turning what has been the scraping loop into a def (I'm still super new to these), then trying to call it under both conditions (main page only and or sub pages as they exist) and iterate or traverse as available. I don't like asking questions here, so many harsh response that berate a questioner. So by the time I'm here asking, I'm felling like I've hit a wall. Thank you for your encouragement, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a solution that meets my needs. It might not be Pythonic.
It allows me to control the depth of search at the city level.
I added an input for the number (depth) of sub-pages to loop through (default is 1) at the city level.
I added an additional for loop *for page in pages* and nested my main loop inside of that.
The main loop will break and move to the next city main page when element (EC: pagination) is not found.

```
root_url = input("enter root URL here")
sub_pages = input("number of sub-pages to scrape")

for loop (from root_url retrieve links for states with providers)
    states_urls = 

for loop (from states_urls retrieve urls for cities with providers)
    city_list_urls = 

for loop (from city_list_urls  get.city)
    clink = get(city)
          
    for page in sub_pages [1:]:
        print("Retriving Listings From City Page: ", page)
        urll = session.get(city + "?pagenumber=" + str(page))
        cards = urll.get(containing element)

        for card in cards:
            main scraping code is here
            scrape and parse each "card"
```